# Chrome auto fill not set password value

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Chrome auto fill not set the input password value

```
<input type="password" value="" name="password">
```

After clicking on the page the password set to the right value

Answer (score 2):

Please do check this:

**Old Solution**:

`<form autocomplete="off">`

**New Solution**:

```
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>
```

Comment: I dont want to disabled the auto fill, I want to the password input set to the right value

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<input type="password" autoComplete="off" id="" placeholder="Password"/>
```

Comment: I dont want to disabled the auto fill, I want to the password input set to the right value